# How to make my open source project known?

Tags: open-source

I have a simple project,
which enable to record the voice and execute associated commands. I
think it can be an interesting and useful project. I don't know how to make it known.

I already wrote [an article](http://gcorbel.github.io/blog-en/blog/2013/11/03/sbire-say-what-you-want-and-he-will-do-it/) and I published it on hackernews but it wasn't very popular.

What can I do to make my project known?

Comment: Make it smarter, call it J.A.R.V.I.S. and people will be flocking at your door. On a serious note, if it's a useful program and it solves an itching problem then it will market itself. One initial user would suffice, given the power that social media has these days. Look at Psy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the word out about a new (open-source) library I've developed?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/73832/how-can-i-get-the-word-out-about-a-new-open-source-library-ive-developed) See also: [How to promote an open-source project?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/55536/how-to-promote-an-open-source-project) and questions linked to it